# Reading data off JSON file and saving it to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to upload a JSON file to my express app, read data from the JSON file and save it as a new document in my MongoDB database.
The documents get saved but the fields don't get added, and that is due to the fields being undefined for some reason, How do I fix this?

When I `console.log(obj)` i can see the data but when I `console.log(obj['DataSource_Name'])` for example I get undefined why?

```
app.post("/upload-config", uploads.single("txt"), async (req, res) => {
  // Read the file and send to the callback
  fs.readFile(req.file.path, handleFile);
  let obj;
  // Write the callback function
  function handleFile(err, data) {
    try {
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(obj["DataSource_Name"]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  const config = new ConfigM({
    DataSource_Name: obj.DataSource_Name,
    DataSource_ID: obj.DataSource_ID,
    DataSource_Type: obj.DataSource_Type,
    DataSource_ICON: obj.DataSource_ICON,
    DoubleQuotes_Text: obj.DoubleQuotes_Text,
    Delimeter: obj.Delimeter,
    Field_list: obj.Field_list,
  });

  try {
    await config.save();
    res.send(obj);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is only going to be defined when `fs.readFile` is ready which is NOT as soon as you called it. That happens asyncronously. So after `fs.readFile()` is called, the code just continues executing, creating the config object and `obj` is still not defined.

If you would like to use callback functions as you have here, you probably want your config creation, `config.save()` and `res.send(obj)` to be part of the readFile callback. Maybe to try before refactoring you could simply move the closing `}` right after the `}` of your final catch.

```
app.post("/upload-config", uploads.single("txt"), async (req, res) => {
  // Read the file and send to the callback
  fs.readFile(req.file.path, handleFile);
  let obj;
  // Write the callback function
  function handleFile(err, data) {
    try {
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(obj["DataSource_Name"]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
 
    const config = new ConfigM({
      DataSource_Name: obj.DataSource_Name,
      DataSource_ID: obj.DataSource_ID,
      DataSource_Type: obj.DataSource_Type,
      DataSource_ICON: obj.DataSource_ICON,
      DoubleQuotes_Text: obj.DoubleQuotes_Text,
      Delimeter: obj.Delimeter,
      Field_list: obj.Field_list,
    });

    try {
      await config.save();
      res.send(obj);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```

I am not certain what you precisely are doing by reading the file locally while you got it from the post. Be aware that you will want a lot more security guards all over the place and not accepting path names from the request to decide the path name on your server. But I guess that's all a topic for another stackoverflow question :)

Comment: Hey @Ben Dadsetan, thank you for your response, what do you suggest instead of reading the file locally while getting it from the post?

Comment: There is sadly a lot of things to be worried about in such situations. It does not fit in a comment. Until you are much more familiar with web security, I would suggest you 100% understand that what you are doing is unsafe. Don't do anything mission critical until you gained some skills.

To learn more about what to check, what safeguards to add, what the risks are and how to fix it, I would recommend sites like "Secure Code Warrior" and "OWASP" that can teach you fundamentals of what is secure and how to make it more secure.

Comment: Hey, @Ben Dadsetan thank you so much I will definitely check those out.